# I have a problem when I go to calculate $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left( \frac {2x+a}{2x+a-1}\right)^{x}.$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

The limit:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}
 \left( {\frac {2\,x+a}{2\,x+a-1}} \right) ^{x}$

I make this:

$\left( {\frac {2\,x+a}{2\,x+a-1}} \right) ^{x}$=${{\rm e}^{{\it x\ln} \left( {\frac {2\,x+a}{2\,x+a-1}} \right) }}$

Then:

${{\rm e}^{{\it \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}
 x\ln} \left( {\frac {2\,x+a}{2\,x+a-1}} \right) }}$ = $0\cdot\infty$

Note: I cannot use L'Hopital

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may recall that, as $u \to 0$, by using the Taylor series expansion,
$$
\log(1+u)=u+O(u^2)
$$ one gets, as $x \to \infty$, 
$$
\begin{align}
\log\left(\frac{2x+a}{2x+a-1}\right)&=\log\left(1+\frac1{2x+a-1}\right)
\\\\&=\frac1{2x+a-1}+O\left(\frac1{(2x+a-1)^2}\right)
\\\\&=\frac1{2x+a-1}+O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)
\end{align}
$$ thus, as $x \to \infty$,
$$
x\log\left(\frac{2x+a}{2x+a-1}\right)=\frac{x}{2x+a-1}+O\left(\frac1{x}\right) \to \color{blue}{\frac12}
$$ and, as $x \to \infty$,
$$
\left(\frac{2x+a}{2x+a-1}\right)^x=e^{x\log\left(\frac{2x+a}{2x+a-1}\right)} \to \color{blue}{\sqrt{e}.}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$
\frac{2x+a}{2x+a-1} = 1 + \frac{1}{2x+a-1}
$$

Does that look a little similar to the following now?
$$
\lim_{n->\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n
$$

Answer (score 0):

$(\frac{2x+a}{2x+a-1})^x=(\frac{2x+a+1-1}{2x+a-1})^x=(1+\frac{1}{\alpha})^{\frac{\alpha}{2}+\frac{1-a}{2}}\longrightarrow e^{\frac{1}{2}}$. Where $\alpha=2x+a-1$ and $\alpha\rightarrow \infty,$ when $x\rightarrow\infty$